# Using "A little vanilla framework" to build an upload feature

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Looking at [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest); I am trying to make a file upload using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Here is how I start: I take the code in the *A little vanilla framework* section of the document. Then I first make it work on my own site. Then to implement the upload functionality I want to modify the end of the *register.php* file. Indeed a file transfer to the server is already happening there. To call it an upload I only have to save the file on the server.

I do that after these lines:

```
echo "\n\n:: Files received ::\n\n";
print_r($_FILES);
```

There, I want to write the contents of $_FILES[0] on the server. For that I use this code:

```
$myfile = fopen("MyData.jpg", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $_FILES[0]);

// The three lines below that I have tried instead of the one above do not work either.
//fwrite($myfile, json_encode($_FILES['photos']);
//fwrite($myfile, json_encode($_FILES[photos[0]]);
//fwrite($myfile, json_encode($_FILES['photos'][0]);

fclose($myfile);
```

As a result, there is a file named *MyData.jpg* written on the server as expected, but its length is zero.

I think there is a mistake in the three lines above but, **what did I do wrong?**

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php `$_FILES[0]` isn't the file. It's information *about* the file.

Comment: And it probably won't be `$_FILES[0]`. It'll be `$_FILES['name_of_form_field']`. Which will be an array, which if you want to write that data somewhere you'll want to stringify it using `print_r($_FILES['name_of_form_field'], true)` or `json_encode($_FILES['name_of_form_field'])` or something, so `fwrite` knows what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it, but for the time being it does not work. I have updated my post as well to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll get data here: $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][0].
Try it please.

Or

You could rewrite your code like below:

```
foreach($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'] as $i=>$file){
    if($_FILES['photos']['error'][$i] == 0){
        move_uploaded_file($file, "MyData_".$i.".jpg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Right method is to use

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "MyData.jpg");
```

where "fileToUpload" is the field name you gave for the file button